# Trouble updating my postgresql database via Golang

Tags: postgresql, go

I seem not to be able to update my database via Golang. Inserting data works perfectly but updating seems to be a problem. I tried to get the number of affected rows and it displays 0. I do not know what I`m doing wrongly. Surprisingly, it doesn't give me any errors. I would ned some help at thus point.

```
func updatestart(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    }
    r.ParseForm()
    id := r.FormValue("id")
    if id == "" {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(400), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    row := db.QueryRow(`SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = $1;`, id)
    p := Person{}
    err := row.Scan(&p.Id, &p.Firstname, &p.Lastname, &p.Email, &p.Gender, &p.Country)
    if err != nil && err != sql.ErrNoRows {
        fmt.Println(err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 307)
        return
    }
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "update.html", p)

}

func updateend(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("part 2")
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        fmt.Println("part 2a")
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(405), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
    r.ParseForm()
    p := Person{}
p.Id = r.FormValue("id")
    p.Firstname = r.FormValue("firstname")
    p.Lastname = r.FormValue("lastname")
    p.Email = r.FormValue("email")
    p.Gender = r.FormValue("gender")
    p.Country = r.FormValue("country")

    if p.Firstname == "" || p.Lastname == "" || p.Email == "" || p.Gender == "" || p.Country == "" {
        fmt.Println("All the fields have not been filled.")
        templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "updateend.html", "Your data was NOT updated. Check back to do that")
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(400), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return

    }
    fmt.Println("part 33333")
    p.Id = 0
    res, err := db.Exec("UPDATE person SET id = $1, firstname = $2, lastname = $3, email = $4, gender = $5, country = $6 WHERE id = $1;", p.Id, p.Firstname, p.Lastname, p.Email, p.Gender, p.Country)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "updateend.html", "it did not update records")

        return
    }

        return
    }
    count, err := res.RowsAffected()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(count)
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "updateend.html", "you have successfully updated your data")

}
```

Comment: In `updateend` you're not, ever, setting the `p.Id` so when you pass it to the SQL query the condition `WHERE id = $1` can never return true unless you have a record with `id` equal to `0`.

Comment: I have set p.Id = 0 and I still can successfully update my data. Did i do it the right way? updated my code here too

Comment: @mkopriva  I have updated my code here too

Comment: Id is 0 by default you have to set it to the number that matches the id of the record you want to update

Comment: I did that but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What @mkopriva says.

The Id of the record to be updated must be passed somehow to the backend along with the updated information. The simplest way to pass the Id through a form rendered like this, is to put Id in a hidden field of the form template `update.html`

Since you need to change your string to an integer, we'll be sure to

```
import(
   // existing imports ...
   "strconv"
)
```

We can't be sure the input is an integer.  that means there's an error condition to handle.  If the input is invalid, we

```
p := Person{}
if id, err := strconv.ParseInt(r.FormValue("id"), 10, 64); err != nil {
  // respond 400 to user - bad request
  return
} else {
  p.Id = id
}    
// ... proceed to set other fields in `p` and process input
```

Comment: Ok, I tried p.Id = r.FormValue("id") and got this error . ''cannot use r.FormValue("id") (value of type string) as int value in assignmentcompiler''

Comment: Ok, I tried p.Id = r.FormValue("id") and got an error

Comment: I updated my answer to show handling the integer conversion, including the error cases